# /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist ProductVersion vs. ProductUserVisibleVersion

Tags: macos, version

The `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` file contains information about the current MacOS such as os name, version information, copyright information etc.

E.g:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
    <string>10K549</string>
    <key>ProductCopyright</key>
    <string>1983-2011 Apple Inc.</string>
    <key>ProductName</key>
    <string>Mac OS X</string>
    <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
    <string>10.6.8</string>
    <key>ProductVersion</key>
    <string>10.6.8</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So far so good, but I wonder what's the difference between the `ProductVersion` key and the `ProductUserVisibleVersion` key.

So far I've never seen a difference between them.

Comment: Closevoter: sorry, this **is** about programming.